# sendmail_path in php.ini for unix [full name of email sender]

Tags: php, email, unix, sendmail, php-ini

I have a Unix base server and a php base website on it. I am trying to set *full name* and *email address* for the **sendmail_path** in php.ini.
When I set it as below (without name) it works fine

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f'emailaddress@example.com'
```

but if I try to add name as below it fails

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f'"Full Name" <emailaddress@example.com>'
```

You may suggest to use `sendmail_from` instead but as I mentioned it's Unix server and whatever is set in `sendmail_from` will be ignored. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Any help will be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the spaces between Full, Name and the e-mail by using a backslash + space (`\ `)?

Comment: I tried with `\\` before the double quotations but not for space, I will try it now

Comment: @Diamondo25 no it does not work; I tried `"Full\ Name"\ <emailaddress@example.com>` I tried `"Full+Name"+<emailaddress@example.com>` but still does not work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the version below:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -F"Full Name" -f'emailaddress@example.com'
```

**WARNINGS**

- It will work with "real sendmail" (sendmail provided by sendmail.org).
- It **may** not work with some "sendmail look alike" provided by other MTAs e.g. postfix, exim, ...
- "Sendmail by sendmail.org" by default adds "warning headers" when `-f` command line option is used.

Comment: Thanks that works fine; I learned to enable full name we need to use `-F` and to enable email address we need to use `-f`